# Generate 2D list with given dimensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamically-generated

I am trying to generate a list of lists with a specified dimension.
the data type of this list looks something like this:

```
data A = X | Y | Z
```

so the list is of type [[**A**]]. (A is an instance of the Show type class so don't worry about that).

The user gives in a certain dimension (lets say width = 3 and height = 4), so the content could look like this:

```
[[X,Y,Z],
 [Y,Y,X],
 [Y,X,Z],
 [X,Z,Z]]
```

How can I generate a *width* X *height* 'matrix', the values aren't all that important at the moment.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** (for clarity reasons)

I just want to know how to generate a 'matrix' of type [[A]] with the width and height as user input.
So width = number of elements in the inner list, height = number of lists in the outer list.

Answer (score 4):

To generate a 3x4 nested list filled by a certain element, you can use:

```
data A = X | Y | Z deriving (Show)
generate width height = replicate height . replicate width

main = print $ generate 3 4 X
```

to get `[[X,X,X],[X,X,X],[X,X,X],[X,X,X]]`.

Note that nested lists are not a great substitute for a 2D array in C/Java if the goal is to do frequent point updates. In those cases, use `Data.Map` or `Data.Array`.